# how to write a 8085 assembly language to sort 5 data bytes in ascending order

Tags: homework, 8085

Needed advise on how to program using 8085 simulator. tried many ways but could not get the answer

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: @DaveTweed whoops, looks like you put it on hold just before I posted.. sorry...

Comment: Also, this is not an EE question, but a programming question, but even for StackOverflow.com, it would be woefully underexplained.

Comment: you want a bubble sort in assembly code? First you need to know the base address of the 5-byte array. Then you need a TEMP variable, to avoid over-writing one of the two variables you will be swapping as you repeatedly scan the 5-byte array. And you need a couple counters (that increment 1,2,3,4. And you need to compare array(2) against array(3), for example and perform a conditional swap using the TEMP variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the program using the **Bubble Sort Algorithm**.

- Get one element in the accumulator.
- **Compare** it with the next element.
- If it is **greater**, swap the elements else increment the index.
- If after one complete loop, there is no exchange, halt the program, the list is already sorted. Else start the whole loop again. So it has to be solved using nested loops.

You will be required to use **JC**, **CPI**, **CMP**,**JNZ**, etc to build up the solution.

This is how the algorithm works. I am sure you can work your way up.

For reference : Visit https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/8085-program-bubble-sort/

I would suggest to you. solve the problem on your own and then check for the link.

All the best.

Answer (score 1):

**Technique**

The classic ["Bubble Sort" algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) is appropriate when implementing a sort function from scratch. If you had an operating system available, there should be a library containing QuickSort, a much better sort algorithm. But in embedded systems programming such as 8085, often we are in the wilderness and must build from scratch. Not only is standard library sometimes unavailable, but the debugging tools tend to be very primitive. So we have to break problem into simple, robust components, and think about how to test each little piece. **What is really valuable here is not the 8085 code itself, but the technique for developing working code using simple tools and a lot of imagination.**

I'm assuming you have an 8085 simulator or development kit with a rudimentary debugger, that can:

- read registers
- write registers
- read memory
- write memory
- single step one instruction at a time
- run until breakpoint

I'm also assuming that you have access to the 8085 instruction set and Technical Reference Manual. For another microprocessor, the instructions will be slightly different, but the basic techniques are similar.

**Algorithm**

Bubble Sort algorithm is not efficient for long lists, but straightforward to implement from scratch:

1. Initialize a flag ("swapped") to false; this flag will be set if any elements were out of order.
2. Index loop i through array contents; array size is known in advance. If array size is N then index values from first element index 0 to (N-2), not including the last element index (N-1).
3. Retrieve indexed element i from array.
4. Retrieve indexed element i+1 from array.
5. Compare adjacent elements, and if they are out of order, then swap (exchange) those two elements i and i+1. Also set "swapped" flag true if there was an exchange.
6. Repeat the loop until all adjacent pairs have been tested.
7. If the "swapped" flag was true, then repeat the process. If the "swapped" flag is false, then the array is in order.

**Debugging**

Plan for debugging, bring up the program a little at a time. **Start with only the array indexing loop** (*items #2, #3, and #6 in the list above*). Traditionally, the 8085 register pair `HL` is used for memory access and `C` (or `BC`) is used for length count, so in the start of the loop, `move immediate` the value `5` into `C` and use `LXI` to load the 16-bit array address into register `HL`. Within the loop, move `A` from `M` (the memory value whose address HL points to), then `decrement` register `C` and `jump if not zero` back to the top of the loop. Step through this code in the debugger and verify that your loop retrieves each element of the array into register `A`.

Next, **modify the loop so that it stops just before the final element**, and within the loop, retrieve element i into register `A` and retrieve element i+1 into register `B`. To get the i+1 array element, use `inx` to increment register `HL` before retrieving `M` into `B`, and use `dcx` to decrement `HL` to restore the index value. (*This takes care of items #2, #3, #4, and #6*.) Step through the code in the debugger, and verify that your code retrieves each adjacent pair of elements into registers `A` and `B`. The code should terminate after comparing 4 pairs, because there are 5 elements in the list.

Once that is working, next work on item #5 **comparing the adjacent elements** (register `A` and `B`). The `sub` subtract or `cmp` compare instructions are appropriate for this, together with a conditional jump instruction. This is also a good time to implement the "swapped" flag (*item #1, #5, and #7*). Test using an already-sorted array: if presented with ( 1 2 3 4 5 ) then the loop should run through the list once, and leave the "swapped" flag false. This validates the compare was implemented correctly.

Finally, implement the **element swap** (*completing item #5 and finishing the entire algorithm*). This part is a little "dangerous" because it writes to memory. If the `HL` register points to the wrong place when you `mov M,A` then there is a potential to do some harm, so be sure to check `HL` is correct using the debugger. Where previously you did `mov A,M`; `inx HL`; `mov B,M`; `dcx HL` -- now you store in opposite order: `mov M,B`; `inx HL`; `mov M,A`; `dcx HL`.

**Testing**

Now that the whole bubble sort is implemented, test for some common edge cases:

Test with ( **1, 2, 3, 4, 5** ), expect there should be no swap, and it should terminate after one pass.

Test with ( **1, 2, 4, 3, 5** ), expect one swap after the first pass, and it should terminate after two passes.

Test with ( **2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 1** ), expect one swap after the first pass, and it should terminate after two passes. The final list should be ( 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1 ), note the **sentinel element 1 is beyond the end of the list** and should not be sorted into the list. **It is very common to have off-by-one errors.** If the array indexing count was too big by one, then the sort routine would incorrectly grab elements from beyond the end of the list.

Test with ( **5, 4, 3, 2, 1** ), expect it should terminate after five passes. This is the most inefficient case for bubble sort, where the initial list was sorted in reverse order. Since the list is fairly short and the focus is on developing code, we can ignore the poor efficiency in this case.

Test with ( **1, 1, 1, 1, 1** ), expect there should be no swap, and it should terminate after one pass. If it tries to repeat forever, then the compare function is not deciding A=B correctly. If A=B then there should be no swap.

You didn't indicate whether you wanted to sort data that is in **2's complement** format (values from -128 to +127) or **offset binary** format (value from 0 to 255). Either way is fine, it only affects how you implemented the comparison function. It will be a subtract or a compare, only difference is which combination of flags (`Z`/`NZ`, `C`/`NC`) triggers an element swap.

Assuming your data is in 2's complement: Test with ( **-2, -1, 0, 1, 2** ), expect there should be no swap, and it should terminate after one pass. If it sorts the list into ( 0, 1, 2, -2, -1 ) the the comparison is treating the values as offset binary (value from 0 to 255) instead of 2's complement (values from -128 to +127).

Assuming your data is not in 2's complement: Test with ( **0, 1, 2, 254, 255** ), expect there should be no swap, and it should terminate after one pass. If it sorts the list into ( 254, 255, 0, 1, 2 ) the the comparison is treating the values as 2's complement (values from -128 to +127) instead of offset binary (value from 0 to 255).

**Documentation**

Code can be hard to read and understand, especially low-level assembly language. At minimum, each major function or major block of code should have some comment lines that explain in words what the code is intended to accomplish.  Keeping track of register assignment is also important. For example, a code fragment like this

```
    mov A,M
    inx HL
    mov B,M
    dcx HL
```

should be documented like this

```
;
; Retrieve adjacent array elements i, i+1
; On Entry: HL = address of element i
; On Exit: A and B will be overwritten
    mov A,M     ; A = content of element i
    inx HL      ; HL = address of element i+1
    mov B,M     ; B = content of element i+1
    dcx HL      ; HL = address of element i
; A = content of element i
; B = content of element i+1
; HL = address of element i
;
```

Once you get a piece of code working, you will tend to hold on to that code and use it as a reference when developing more code. After 6 months you will not remember how the program works, it will be like reading code that another person wrote. **Be nice to your future self, and spend time writing good comments as you code.**

Here's an example of how much documentation I would be putting in, if I were developing this code. This is based on decades of real-world experience writing code, both at high level and at low level. If it seems like half of what you're writing is documentation, just remember it's easier than debugging a pile of raw hex codes. Also note the tags @brief, @code/@endcode, @pre, @post, @param[in], @param[out], @return are useful if you ever run your code through an automated documentation tool like doxygen.

```
;--------------------------------------------------
; Bubble Sort
;
; @brief Sort an array of 8-bit 2's complement values.
; Array must be write accessible memory.
;
; @TODO incomplete, not fully implemented, needs debug
;
; Usage:
; @code
;   lxi  HL, _array
;   mvi  C,  _sizeof_array
;   call BubbleSort
; @endcode
;
; @pre On Entry:
;   @param[in] HL = address of array
;   @param[in] C  = length of array (0 to 255)
;
; @post On Exit:
;   The array is sorted in place in memory.
;
; @test ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ) expect there should be no swap, and it should terminate after one pass.
;
; @test ( 1, 2, 4, 3, 5 ) expect one swap after the first pass, and it should terminate after two passes.
;
; @test ( 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 1 ) expect one swap after the first pass, and it should terminate after two passes, final ( 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1 ), note the sentinel element 1 is beyond the end of the list.
;
; @test ( 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ) expect it should terminate after five passes.
;
; @test ( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ) expect there should be no swap, and it should terminate after one pass.
;
; @test ( -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 ) expect there should be no swap, and it should terminate after one pass.
;
BubbleSort:
    push PSW    ; save registers
    push B
    push D
    push H
    ;
    mov  D,H    ; save start of array in DE
    mov  E,L    
    ; DE = address of array
    ;
    ; initialize swapped flag
    mvi  a, #0
    sta  _swappedFlag
    ;
    ... more code goes here ...
    ;
    ; A = temporary, content of element i
    ; B = temporary, content of element i+i
    ; C = countdown from array size-1 to 0
    ; HL = address of element i
    ;--------------------------------------------------
outerLoop:
    mov  H,D    ; save start of array in DE
    mov  L,E
    ; HL = address of element i
    ;
    mov  C, _sizeof_array
    dec c   ; indexing adjacent pairs, do not index last element
    ;
    ;--------------------------------------------------
innerLoop:
        ;
        ; Retrieve adjacent array elements i, i+1
        ; On Entry: HL = address of element i
        ; On Exit: A and B will be overwritten
        mov A,M     ; A = content of element i
        inx HL      ; HL = address of element i+1
        mov B,M     ; B = content of element i+1
        dcx HL      ; HL = address of element i
        ; A = content of element i
        ; B = content of element i+1
        ; HL = address of element i
        ;
        ... more code goes here for comparing and exchange ...
        ;
        ; C = countdown from array size-1 to 0
        dec c
        jnz innerLoop
    ;--------------------------------------------------
    ; 
    ; if "swapped" flag was set, repeat outerLoop
    lda  _swappedFlag
    jnz  outerLoop
    ;--------------------------------------------------
    ;
    pop  H      ; restore registers
    pop  D
    pop  B
    pop  PSW
    ret
;--------------------------------------------------
```